# calculate an integral in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, integral

I need to calculate an integral in python.

I have imported sympy.

```
 g(a,z) = integral_from_z_to_inf of ( t^(a-1) * e^(-1))
```

in python:

```
 x,a,z = symbols('x a z')
 g = integrate(x**(a-1) * exp(-x), z, oo)
```

I got error:

```
 ValueError: Invalid limits given: (z, oo)
```

---

I called:

```
b,c,mean,variance  = S('b c mean variance'.split())

ff1 = b*g((1+c), lb / b)  // lb is a constant, b and c are unknown var that I need to solve. and mean and variance are constants.
```

I got error:

```
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am on Python 2.7, but your problems seems to be not reading the documentation closely enough.  The docs say:

> var can be:
>
> - a symbol – indefinite integration
> - a tuple (symbol, a) – indefinite integration with result
>
>   given with a replacing symbol
> - a tuple (symbol, a, b) – definite integration

You want to perform the last one, so you need to use a tuple.

The command you are looking for is:

```
import sympy as sym


x, a, z = sym.symbols('x a z')
g = sym.integrate(x**(a-1) * sym.exp(-x), (x, z, sym.oo))
```

Comment: @user3440244 Your new question is different from your old one. If you want to ask another question, please open a new question using the "Ask Question" button above.